# Conditional Tag - woocommerce customer - logged in - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, conditional-statements, woocommerce

I'm looking for the conditional tag (or code / wordpress) to check if a visitor is logged in to the 'basic' *Customer* role of Woocommerce.

if ( is_user_logged_in() only checks if the visitor is logged in... so this needs te be more specific but I don't know how...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As `current_user_can( 'customer' )` is [unreliable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes), you could roll your own function, as suggested [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624#comment:11). In `functions.php`:

```
function so19916370_get_user_role( $user_id = 0 )
{
    $user = ( $user_id ) ? get_userdata( $user_id ) : wp_get_current_user();
    return current( $user->roles );
}
```

Usage, checking the ID of the current user:

```
if( 'customer' == so19916370_get_user_role( get_current_user_id() ) )
{
    echo 'you are a customer';
}
```